# AngularJS: Calling same API with updated params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

Task - I have to merge the response array into one. I am calling the same API but passing the different 'skip' param. the skip param is dynamic, based on last response.

```
Call #1 - api(id, skip=0)
Call #2 - api(id, skip+1)
...
```

Here is my code:

```
function appendArray(jobId, skip, count) {
  appSegmentService.csvDownload(jobId, skip, count)
    .then(function(resp) {
      var arr = [];

      arr = arr.concat(resp.data);
      skip += 5000;

      if (resp.data.length === 5000) {
        arr = arr.concat(appendArray(jobId, skip, count));
      } else {
        console.log(arr);
      }

    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: `appendArray` should return a promise. So add `return` statements and don't use `concat`, but `.then(nextArr => arr.concat(nextArr))`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use lodash package for the same its pretty handy for all array operations visit https://lodash.com/docs/

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var arr=[];
function appendArray(jobId, skip, count) {
                    var localArray=appSegmentService.csvDownload(jobId, skip, count)
                        .then(function (resp) {
                            var arr = [];

                            arr = arr.concat(resp.data);
                            skip += 5000;

                            if (resp.data.length === 5000) {

                               return arr = arr.concat(appendArray(jobId, skip, count));
                            } else {
                                console.log(arr);
                            }

                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                       arr=_.concat(arr,localArray);
                       return arr;

                }
```